# AWS SageMaker: ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member error

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

i'm working with AWS SageMaker and i'm trying to recreating my own model taking as example the movie genre predictions.

That's the code:

```
def split(df, test_size):
    data = df.values
    data_y = df.drop(['luogo', 'testo', 'lingua'], axis=1).values
    #StratifiedShuffleSplit does not work with one hot encoded / multiple 
    labels. Doing the split on basis of arg max labels.
    data_y = np.argmax(data_y, axis=1)
    data_y.shape
    stratified_split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, 
test_size=test_size, random_state=42)
    for train_index, test_index in stratified_split.split(data, data_y):
        train, test = df.iloc[train_index], df.iloc[test_index]
     return train, test

train, test = split(df, 0.33)
#Split the train further into train and validation
train, validation = split(train, 0.2)
```

This is the dataframe: 
[image]

And this is the example dataframe:

[image]

[image]

This is the error:

```
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

How can i modify my df?

Notice that the example df has more than one '1' in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

**It looks like there is a class in data_y that only has one entry associated with it, when it is expecting at least 2.**

> Notice that the example df has more than one '1' in the same row.

The error message its attempting to communicate that your data has a particular class that only has one entry (row) of data for it, not that it only has one feature (column) in its entry.

Due to the way Stratified Split works, it tries to split the data so that it makes `n_splits` number of sets. In order for it to do this, you need at least `n_splits` number of entries for each class so that each set gets at least one entry for said class. You have your `n_splits` value set to 2, but since you have a class that only has one entry, it cant split one entry into two sets.

The solution to this would be to include more data for that class, or remove the data for that class.

Comment: Well, i can't understand what to add: should i add more genres?

Comment: My guess is that you have a genre that only has one movie (I assume they're movies) associated with it. You need to add more movies so there's at least two entries for each genre